# Use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML but gets stuck in creating BeatuifulSoup object

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html5lib')
```

After running several times, the process gets stuck at `BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html5lib')`, and I have tried to change from html parser to 'lxml' and 'html.parser'. However, the problem persists. Is there a bug in BeautifulSoup? How can I solve this problem?

**update**
I add some logs inside the program, like this

```
print('open the url')
html = urlopen(url)
print('create BeautifulSoup Object')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html5lib')
```

The console print `create BeautifulSoup Object` and just stay there with a blinking cursor.

Comment: further details on "gets stuck" would be helpful, is there an error, a timeout??

Comment: No error. the program just get stuck in there.

Comment: The most likely problem is that it is actually getting stuck on the html.read() call and that BeautifulSoup is not to blame.  Maybe pull the html.read() out to make sure your problem is really with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Maybe you are right! I also have passed argument `html` to `BeautifulSoup` and encounter same problem. I guess that call `html.read()` inside `BeautifulSoup.__init__` . Actually, I find this code in `BeautifulSoup.__init__`, `if hasattr(markup, 'read'): markup = markup.read()` Thank you very much!

Comment: Does getting stuck on 'html.read()' means there are issues on Networks?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and I found out that the program got stuck at `html.read()`, which may because `urlopen()` resource does not close correctly when the response has some errors.

You can change like this:

```
with urlopen(url) as html:
    html = html.read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Or you can choose to use the `requests` package, which is better than the `urllib` like this:

```
import requests

html = requests.get(url).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Hope it can solve your problem